# How solve the undefined value in jest angular unit testing?

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jest-fetch-mock

I have passed the api response value from one function to another function, But in JEST unit test case showing undefined, How to solve this error

angular  code

```
  this.content = this.commonSiteContent();
 this.passingvalue(this.content.name);


 jest.spyOn(srvice, 'commonSiteContent').mockReturnValue(mockContent);
component.ngOnInit();
expect(mockContent.getContentDetails).toHaveBeenCalledWith("sss");
expect(component.passvalue).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

I got the below error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
  27 |   
  28 |
  29 |     this.passvalue(this.content.name);
     |                                     ^
  30 |   }
  31 |   passvalue(name="" ){
```

Comment: The content doesnt have property `name` either you can assign the content object or use safe navigator operator `?` i.e `this.passvalue(this.content?.name);`

Comment: The content values return from API, After getting just pass another function @KamranKhatti

Comment: Not sure how you implemented and can not provide solution without seeing the code if you have any working example may be on stackblitz etc then it will help to fix.

Comment: I have updated angular and unit test code